# flipping cards in a card game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uiviewanimation, playing-cards

I develop a game where when user touches a card it'll flip slowly and number will show up.
For that purpose , what cocos2d API can I use ?

Or should I create animation with frames indicating the flip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Flipping a view u can do it like this ,

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:myview cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Before doing animation just create a label and add it as a subview to the UIView. Set the text to the number u want to display after the animation.Hide this label.At the end of the animation that is after commitAnimations just set the hidden property of the label to NO. You will achieve the animation style u want ,  i guess.. Hope this helps....Happy coding... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the implementation with 2 UIImageViews and it's working. I placed image views on top of each other and when I click the active card it flips and the other card is show.(the hidden property of active card will go to YES). But there is a problem. A transition spans  360 degree flip so I see the active card once again before it goes to hidden state. you got my problem ? so transition is not very smooth.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something similar to `CCTransitionFlipX`. But instead of CCScene let it operate on your card nodes (sprites).

Here is the implementation of this class (CCTransition.m):

```
//
// FlipX Transition
//
@implementation CCTransitionFlipX
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    CCActionInterval *inA, *outA;
    [inScene_ setVisible: NO];

    float inDeltaZ, inAngleZ;
    float outDeltaZ, outAngleZ;

    if( orientation == kOrientationRightOver ) {
        inDeltaZ = 90;
        inAngleZ = 270;
        outDeltaZ = 90;
        outAngleZ = 0;
    } else {
        inDeltaZ = -90;
        inAngleZ = 90;
        outDeltaZ = -90;
        outAngleZ = 0;
    }

    inA = [CCSequence actions:
           [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:duration_/2],
           [CCShow action],
           [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration: duration_/2 radius: 1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:inAngleZ deltaAngleZ:inDeltaZ angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0],
           [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finish)],
           nil ];
    outA = [CCSequence actions:
            [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration: duration_/2 radius: 1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:outAngleZ deltaAngleZ:outDeltaZ angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0],
            [CCHide action],
            [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:duration_/2],                           
            nil ];

    [inScene_ runAction: inA];
    [outScene_ runAction: outA];

}
@end
```

Basically it runs a sequence of CCActions on both scenes with the given duration. The  `CCOrbitCamera` action orbits the camera around the center of the screen using spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

[GeekGameBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html) is a mac app which has a bunch of games in it. It also has a card class which handles flips and the like. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do in cocs2d-android-1 like that

```
CCSprite sprite=CCSprite.sprite("icon.png");
CCIntervalAction a = (CCIntervalAction)CCOrbitCamera.action(2, 1, 0, 0, 360, 0, 0);
addChild(sprite,1);
sprite.runAction(CCRepeatForever.action(a));
```